# jquery $(this).attr('href') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, href, attr

I've got a very simple code

HTML

```
<a class="qqPopupCTA" href="http://example.com">Button</a>
```

JS

```
$qqPopupCTA = $('.qqPopupCTA');

function showForm(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var targetPageUrl = $(this).attr('href');

    // do stuff
}

$qqPopupCTA.on('click', function(e){showForm(e);});
```

However I keep getting undefined href. Console.log($(this)) returns "window" and console.dir($(this)) returns "e.fn.init[1]"

Any idea what am I doing wrong? The code is super simple so I must be missing something obvious.

I think I've tried everything.

Comment: `$qqPopupCTA.on('click', showForm);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `showForm(e)`, the context(`this`) is not the anchor object inside `showForm` it is the window object.

So you can just pass the function reference as the click handler

```
$qqPopupCTA.on('click', showForm);
```

```js
$qqPopupCTA = $('.qqPopupCTA');

function showForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetPageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
  alert(targetPageUrl)

  // do stuff
}

$qqPopupCTA.on('click', showForm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="qqPopupCTA" href="http://example.com">Button</a>
```

or pass a custom context to the `showForm` function using `.call()`

```
$qqPopupCTA.on('click', function (e) {
    showForm.call(this, e);
});
```

```js
$qqPopupCTA = $('.qqPopupCTA');

function showForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetPageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
  alert(targetPageUrl)

  // do stuff
}

$qqPopupCTA.on('click', function(e) {
  showForm.call(this, e)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="qqPopupCTA" href="http://example.com">Button</a>
```

Comment: It works! I don't know how but the second option works. The first one didn't pass the event to e.preventDefault but the second one works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @KrzysztofPłaneta first one also should work - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9qLq9zqr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$qqPopupCTA.on('click', showForm); // pass function name(ref)
```

Or

```
$qqPopupCTA.on('click', function(e){
      showForm.call(this,e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your approach `this` in the function `setCurrent` doesn't refers to the element which invoked the event. it is `window` object

Just pass function reference to when binding event

```
$qqPopupCTA.on('click', showForm);
```

OR, You can use `bind()`

```
$qqPopupCTA.on('click', function (e) {
    showForm.bind(this)(e);
});
```

Comment: Arun's second solution worked and the second one of yours did too. Thank you!

Comment: @KrzysztofPłaneta, Even first one should also work and that's recommended

Answer (score 0):

The function showForm is defined globally , 'this' refers to window object .
showForm(e,this) will give the reference of current element to the function.so passing the 'this' should fix your undefined this

Answer (score 0):

$('.qqPopupCTA').on('click', function showForm() {
    var targetPageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(targetPageUrl)

});